# How to append first element of two lists in LISP

Tags: scheme, lisp

I am very green on LISP, i am trying to take 2 list and merging them.

```
(define (append lst1 lst2)
        (if (null? lst1) lst2
            (cons (car lst1) (append (cdr lst2) lst2))))
(append '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6 7 8))
```

this results in

(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)

where i wanted to have first element of both list, and if empty it fills with the rest of the other list.

(1 4 2 5 3 6 7 8)

Comment: This isn't Common Lisp; it looks like Scheme. Also, this surely isn't the actual code that gave the results you suggested: `list1` and `list2` are not parameters of `append` as defined here. This code should work when the typos are fixed.

Comment: @adabsurdum fixed, but it still returns ( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ) which is not correct, as i want to have (1 4 2 5 3 6 7 8)

Comment: I missed the ordering bit; you still have two typos then: `list2` -> `lst2`, and `(1 2 3 4 5 6)` -> `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)`.

Comment: @adabsurdum ah yes, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You need to switch the order of the list inputs on each recursive call so that you can alternate which element is taken for the result list. You should also rename from `append` to something else, since you are not really doing an append procedure, and that name is a bit misleading:

```
(define (merge lst1 lst2)
  (if (null? lst1)
      lst2
      (cons (car lst1) (merge lst2 (cdr lst1)))))
```

```
> (merge '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6 7 8))
(1 4 2 5 3 6 7 8)
```

Comment: You need to check for both lists being empty and return the other one I think, or you'll hit nastiness.

Comment: @tfb -- I was testing the wrong list; you only need to test `lst1` because that is the one that gets operated on by `car`. Thanks for the ping ;)

Comment: Oh, yes, that's right.  You'll get one extra call (which doesn't matter, obviously) but the code is much easier to read your way.